# ruby on rails: tabs for different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm doing a ruby on rails app and I have 3 tabs that order my posts by votes, recent and oldest. The tabs only change a partial staying on the same page without refreshing. How can I do this but with 3 different pages? for example `http://127.0.0.1:3333/performance_indicators/1?votes` `http://127.0.0.1:3333/performance_indicators/1?recent` `http://127.0.0.1:3333/performance_indicators/1?oldest`

**I want to change the page refreshing it (similar to the tab system of stackOverflow)**

my html tabs are like this :

```
<div id="tabs-container" >
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active test" id="recent" title="Order recommendations by Votes"><a href="#tab-1" >Votes</a></li>
        <li class="test" id="votes" title="Order recommendations by Recent"><a href="#tab-2">Recent</a></li>
        <li class="test" id="oldest" title="Order recommendations by Oldest"><a href="#tab-3">Oldest</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
        <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order(cached_votes_score: :desc), locals: { tab: "votes" } %></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
        <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at DESC"), :locals => { tab: "recent" } %></p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at ASC") , :locals => { tab: "oldest" } %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and this is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("active");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();

    });

});
```

How can I render this partials in 3 different pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a parameter along with the url to specify which tab to select like :

```
<div id="tabs-container" >
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'votes' %> test" id="votes" title="Order recommendations by Votes"><a href="/performance_indicators/1?tab=votes" >Votes</a></li>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'recent' %> test" id="recent" title="Order recommendations by Recent"><a href="/performance_indicators/1?tab=recent">Recent</a></li>
        <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:tab] == 'oldest' %> test" id="oldest" title="Order recommendations by Oldest"><a href="/performance_indicators/1?tab=oldest">Oldest</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
  <% collection = [] %>
  <% if params[:tab] == "votes" %>
      <% collection = @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order(cached_votes_score: :desc) %>
  <% elsif params[:tab] == "recent" %>
      <% collection = @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at DESC") %>
  <% elsif params[:tab] == "oldest" %>
      <% collection = @performance_indicator.improvement_actions.order("created_at ASC") %>
  <% end %>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <p><%= render partial: 'improvement_actions/improvement_action', collection: collection, locals: { tab: params[:tab] } %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This will work with redirect links as 3 pages you want.